# Process Builder fails when adding VF markup in Comment field

Tags: process-builder

I have a Process Builder where if you add a comment on a "Response" ield in the Case-Comment object then it takes that comment and updates the "New Comment" field in the Case object. This PB was working fine until we hit one scenario. Just a background, this object is basically our way of communicating with out customers and helping them with any developer related issues they may have. In this particular scenario, a customer had a coding related problem, so I tried sending him some apex code. When I pasted the apex code in the "Response" field, the PB failed. It keeps on giving me vague errors
`"We can't save this record because the "Case Comment: Update Case Fields" process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. <b>An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow</b><br>An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information. Error ID: 1557112563-28907 (-630144534).` The debug logs doesnt help either. It works for every other comment I am making, but when I put apex code such as this:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="
{!salesInvoice.c2g__Dimension2__r.Logo_URL__c != ''}
">
<apex:image URL="
{!salesInvoice.c2g__Dimension2__r.Logo_URL__c}
"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

it fails! I have tried putting quotes around it, tried converting to a Lightning flow, but nothing works. Can someone please help?
​​​​​​​Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you're putting that 'code' in the comments field?

Comment: Yes. Its a custom field btw and its a long text. I should be able to put anything that field. I can say "Hello try this.." or put that snippet in it. Its essentially to respond to the customer

Comment: so, the PB error should show up in an email that will be sent to whomever is configured in Setup | Process Automations and that will contain more details on the actual fault.

Comment: Unfortunately all the email says is the statement that I pasted in the question